# Shopify navigation menu not showing product pictures. How to fix?

Tags: shopify

This liquid code does not showed the product picture on the navigation menu.

```
{% assign collection-menu = linklists.indoor-navigation %}
  {% for link in collection-menu.links %}
    {{ link.title }}
    {% for sub_link in link.links %}
      {{ sub_link.title }}
        {% for sub_sub_link in sub_link.links %}
          {% if sub_sub_link.type == "product_link" %}
            <img src="{{ sub_sub_link.object | img_url: "250x250"}}"/>
          {% endif %}
          {{ sub_sub_link.title }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

What is the problem? Please, your support.

Comment: Is it normal that product image is required only for 3rd level navin your code?